# Can I say "someone is ample"?

Tags: grammar, formality, grammaticality

My friend appoints someone to be our spokesperson in an interview. And I think this person is enough to answer all questions, thus my friend does not need to find another spokesperson.

I want to reply to my friend's email by saying **"Mr. X is ample to be the spokesperson for our interview"** (I want to use formal tone)

Is this correct?

Please help, thanks :)

Comment: Not a good choice. It’s an adjective whose most common meaning is “fat.”

Comment: @Xanne: A meaning memorably invoked in the movie "Hairspray" by Mr. Pinky's Hefty Hideaway House of Fashion for the Ample Woman.

Comment: Try: is sufficiently qualified...    The problem really starts with your first sentence: *is enough*  Which treats the person as a measurable quantity.  And then you change *enough* to *ample* to up the register.  Instead you need something like “is good enough” or “is smart enough” or “is knowledgeable enough” is “capable enough” Once you have that you can see that *ample* is not a good replacement. But *sufficiently* is nice “big” word: is sufficiently capable, qualified, knowledgeable, intelligent...

Comment: You’re writing to a friend, so no need to be formal unless you expect the e-mail to be copied or forwarded. Why not just say: “Mr. X would be a very sound choice for this assignment. No need to have a second.”  Don’t forget that sometimes it’s useful to send a larger delegation for the sake of appearances or to reward someone with an outing and a free lunch.